# Creating a fake textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For a project I'm working on, I need to be able to show "divs" before the text contents of a textarea :

[image]

At first I thought I could just place the divs with absolute positioning and z-index, but that would entail "pushing" the text, and making sure that the user can't remove those first spaces, not with backspace nor ctrl+c nor ctrl+x nor delete ... It looked complicated to get every possible way.

Now, I'm trying to use a "div" made to look like a textarea, which contains an **editable** "span" that will contain the text :

[image]

That works for the moment, but it's not perfect, especially in terms of :focus (clicking anywhere on the outer div should display the cursor in the text span*), and it seems to break if I empty the text span.

Any ideas on how to fix this ? I'm open to suggestions, even if I have to change the structure of my fake textarea.

It should work on all major (recent) browsers, and can use jQuery.

- `$('#outerDiv').bind('click', $('#outerDiv span.text').focus());` seems to work in Chrome but not in firefox.

Comment: You can always put focus on the span with a click event on the container

Comment: Does the text in the textarea *have* to start on the same line as the divs? If you could start it on the next line, it would be a lot easier.

Comment: hope this help http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/

Comment: @GregL : If I can't do it I'll make it start under the divs, but it would be prettier if they are on the same line.

Comment: Note, that simulating text selection across spans (to provide the same experience as textarea) will be pain in the a**. I'm not so sure this solution is less complicated than using one textarea and making sure that text is shifted so it starts after div1 or div2.

Comment: See how these guys do it: http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: Chosen creates a fake textbox, not a multiline textarea.

Comment: In what way does it 'break' when you empty the span? How are you emptying the span?

Comment: If I keep pressing backspace, weird things happen, different in Chrome & Firefox. Sometimes the cursor appears on top of the outer div, sometimes it pushes *down* div1 and div2

Comment: It is multipline, it stretches if you add items. I still think its worth a look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I'd do is the following:

1. Your containing element (the text editor) should be a block level element. It is not editable.
2. Your tags should consist of the following: A container that `float`s to the left and `inline-block` or `float`ed children.
3. A **non-floated block** (important) level element that is `contenteditable`.

End result:

```
<div>
  <!-- The list of tags -->
  <ul style="float:left"> 
    <li style="float:left">...</li>
    <li style="float:left">...</li>
    <li style="float:left">...</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- This will contain your text: -->
  <div contenteditable="true">...</div>
</div>
```

If you have a lot of tags, they'll wrap to the next line. Text in the editable element will wrap around the tags as well.

Clicking the tags would not give the editable element focus, but you can remedy that with JavaScript.

[Here's an example I whipped up](http://jsfiddle.net/wbysz/). Works in Safari/Chrome/Firefox. Have not tested Internet Explorer, but it should work fine.